Is there any method to export the content show in commandline with command `\show` to the PDF file?
In the TeXBook, I learn about that the definition of some macros could be shown with the CommandLine in tex environment with \show, like \show\uppercase or \show\proclaim, however,my question is: Is there any method to show the content of \show\cs in the PDF compiled by LaTeX?
Another little problem, I confront an exercise in TeXbook, to \show the definition of ⟨return⟩ and ⟨space⟩, I mistoken when I try to use the \show command in the CommandLine in how to type the ⟨return⟩ symbol (so weird).

example of the \show couldn't work in document with TeXLive2024, which make me regard the macro \show as the CommandLine Command.
\documentclass[margin=1in]{standalone}
\begin{document}

%\show \uppercase % interupt between the compiling process...
\meaning \uppercase

\end{document}


use \meaning insetad of \show

it's not clear why you refer to \show as related to a bash commandline, it is a normal tex command that you can use in a document, it shows the result like an error messgae, on the terminal and in the log. You do not need to call tex from the commandline if you don't normally do that for documents.

why did you edit your question after @DavidCarlisle et al. answered in a way which renders both question and answers nonsense? you now have \meaning in your example and both answers say to use \meaning.

\show works fine in a document with TL2024. however, whatever @DavidCarlisle says, you probably have to compile at the command line for it to work properly because most GUI editors report a compilation failure if you use \show. if you compile on the command line, this isn't a problem. to be clear: this is an issue caused by your editor and not TL.

@cfr but don't the editors run in batchmode so the document still completes and the show output is in the log?

the document you show if you uncomment the \show would work in graphical editors, you say it does not work, but do not say what went wrong, show the log file you get after running that in your editor.

@DavidCarlisle overleaf does but other gui editors I've used don't e.g. kile. it just abandons the attempt. and texshop used to work the same way. (maybe it still does, but I have no idea.) or I've done something wrong in every editor ....

that's weird, \show is just like an error message, so if an editor shows error messages it should show \show

You can use \meaning to show the same information as \show in the output rather than on the terminal.
This document does both and answers the example.

\show\ %
\show\


{1: \tt \meaning\ }

{2: \tt \meaning\
}

\bye

On the terminal (and in the log) the \show produce
> \ =\ .
l.2 \show\ 
           %
? 
> \^^M=macro:
->\ .
l.3 \show\
          
? 

and the generated document shows the \meaning:

Either of these show that in plain TeX \<space> is a TeX primitive and \<newline> is a macro.

a terminal session as requested in comments
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=tex)
**\show\
> \^^M=macro:
->\ .
<*> \show\
          
? x
No pages of output.



Excellent answer for {2: \tt \meaning\ }, I don't know how to type the <return> when in the terminal...

@Explorer just type \  followed by the return key:  I added to the end of my question a terminal session starting from typing tex to the bash $ commandline prompt.

The \show command in TeX is designed to print the definition of a control sequence to the terminal or log file, not the PDF. However, if you want to display the definition of a macro directly in the PDF, you can do so by using the \meaning command instead of \show.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\uppercase}

\def\mycommand{Hello World}
\texttt{\meaning\mycommand}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot! And welcome to the brilliant forum! It worked!

You are welcome
